# Combine two tables in a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My two tables are:

```
PkID | HouseFk | house_extra_id | Price | discount_id
1    | 5       | 6              | 1205  | 0

PkID | HouseFk | PacketFk | Price | discount_id
1    | 6       | 7        | 500   | 0
```

How can I combine those two into a new table which is not stored in a database but only used for output. I already tried `join` and `union all` but I can't get the desired table structure. I want the columns of the first and the second table, with `NULL` values where needed like so:

```
PkID | HouseFk | house_extra_id | Price | discount_id | PacketFk
1    | 5       | 6              | 1205  | 0           | NULL
1    | 6       | NULL           | 500   | 0           | 7
```

If I use `join` on `HouseFk` I only get combined rows where `HouseFk` value is present in both tables and `union all` leaves out some of my columns!

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `union all`, and select `NULL` value where you want to add extra values like this:

```
select PkID , HouseFk , house_extra_id , Price , discount_id, 
NULL AS PacketFk from table_1
union all
select PkID, HouseFk, NULL AS house_extra_id , Price , discount_id, 
PacketFk from table_2
```

Comment: this did it, I think the secret is in the `NULL AS` part, optional question is how would you answer compare to this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9214674/5710524) is it the same as doing `SELECT *
FROM `t1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`

UNION

SELECT *
FROM `t1`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
WHERE `t1`.`id` IS NULL;`

Answer (score 2):

it will work

```
select  pkid,housefk,house_extra_id,price,discount_id,null as packetfk
from T1

union all

select pkid,housefk,null as house_extra_id,price,discount_id,packetfk
from t2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PkID, HouseFK, house_extra_id, Price, discount_id, NULL AS PacketFK FROM tableOne
UNION ALL
SELECT PkID, HouseFK, NULL AS house_extra_id, Price, discount_id, PacketFK FROM tableTwo
```